# alternative function for range() in python

Tags: python, python-unicode

I want to iterate through a text file and print the occurrence of unicode.
In the place of range I want a suitable function.

```
  counter = {}
  x={'0x0985':1,'0x0986':2,'0x0987':3,'0x0988':4,'0x0989':5}
  for key,value in x.items():
     x[key]=0
     with open('bengali.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as infile:
       for line in infile:
         for char in line:
             n = ord(char)
             if n in range{0x0985,0x0986,0x0987,0x0988,0x0989}
               counter[n] += 1
               for key, value in counter.items():
                  print(chr(key), value)
```

Comment: indent your code properly please.

Comment: again, `range{0x0985,0x0986,0x0987,0x0988,0x0989}` is not valid python; `set(range(0x0985, 0x098a))` is...

Comment: what is the return value of set

Comment: `set` is a basic [python datatype](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datatypes.html)...

Comment: i tried with set its not working in both the forms

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why you want to use range here at all.

```
if n in (0x0985,0x0986,0x0987,0x0988,0x0989):
```

Comment: i'd even suggest to use a `set`: `{0x0985,0x0986,0x0987,0x0988,0x0989}` or even `if n in set(range(0x0985, 0x098a))`

Comment: @hiro protagonist I know that range is not a valid one.. What is the alternative to get a count in the above snippet

Comment: @hiroprotagonist 
`python -m timeit "x={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}" "1 in x"`

1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.426 usec per loop

`python -m timeit "x=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)" "1 in x"`

10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0463 usec per loop
Why You suggest set over tuple

Comment: @SmartManoj: setting up the `set` takes most of that time. if you set it up once and test `in` many times you will see significant speedup. also note the difference between `1 in x` and `8 in x` for the tuple.

Answer (score 0):

```
if n in range(2437,2442): #is enough
```

Or

```
if n in range(0x985,0x98a):
```

Or

```
my_unicode=(0x0985,0x0986,0x0987,0x0988,0x0989,0x98A,0x098B,0x098F)
if n in my_unicode:pass
```

Comment: ...those are not equivalent. you mean `range(0x0985, 0x098a)`.

Comment: say i want to include those many unicodes0x0985,0x0986,0x0987,0x0988,0x0989,0x98A,0x098B,0x098F) then range will  not work because there is no continuation in unicodes

Comment: then u could use tuple as said by [Daniel Roseman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman)

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run3.py", line 12, in <module>
    counter[n] += 1
KeyError: 10
 Its showing error if i use tuple as said above

Comment: counter[n]=0 at  10th line or use defaultdict

Comment: use 
`from collections import defaultdict ;
counter=defaultdict(int)`

or use [Counter](https://pymotw.com/3/collections/counter.html)